# Customizing Heroku Apache buildpack

Tags: php, apache, heroku, dokku

I want to change Apache configuration, but I get forbidden after I deploy these settings what could be the problem what I am doing wrong here

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -C httpd.inc.conf -i php.ini public/`

httpd.inc.conf

```
Timeout 30
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 50
KeepAliveTimeout 10

<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers          3
    MinSpareServers       2
    MaxSpareServers       5
    MaxClients            10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

php.ini

```
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 150M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_execution_time = 86400
max_file_uploads = 40
```